# Plot of list of functions have the same colour

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

When I execute

```
Plot[{(# + 1 &)[x], (2*# + 3 &)[x]}, {x, -2, 2}]
```

I get the following plots of different colours (as per the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html)):

[image]

But when I execute

```
{# + 1 &, 2*# + 3 &} // Plot[x // # // Through, {x, -2, 2}] &
```

the plots have the same blue colour:

[image]

Why don't the plots have different colours in the second case, even though the logic results in an equivalent expression?

Comment: Use this `{# + 1 &, 2*# + 3 &} // Plot[Evaluate[x // # // Through], {x, -2, 2}] &`

Comment: This suggestion definitely works for the simple functions above. But in my actual code, I have a list of trained models, and with that list I get the following error: `PredictorFunction: Incompatible variable type (Numerical) and variable value (x).` But then it does go on to plot them anyway.